# Query column created in CASE statement just before - "column does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have this code:

```sql
CASE WHEN url LIKE 'utm_medium' 
    THEN
      SPLIT_PART( -- slice UTM from URL
        SPLIT_PART(pageviews.url,'utm_medium=',2)
        ,'&',1
      )

ELSE NULL END AS utm_medium,

CASE 
    WHEN utm_medium = 'paidsocial'
      THEN channel = 'Paid Social'

    WHEN utm_medium = 'email'
      THEN channel = 'Email'  
END
```

In the first CASE, I extract `utm_medium` param from URL as `utm_medium` column, and in second CASE I'd like to create another column `channel` based on `utm_medium` value.

I'm getting error:

```
column "utm_medium" does not exist
  LINE 153:     WHEN utm_medium = 'paidsocial'
```

Is it possible to query utm_medium column just after it is created?

Comment: You can't re-use an alias on the same level where you defined it

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`split_part()` suggests Postgres, which supports lateral joins.  These allow you to define aliases in the `FROM` clause without using subqueries or CTEs.  That would be:

```
SELECT pv.*, v.utm_medium,
       (CASE WHEN utm_medium = 'paidsocial' THEN channel = 'Paid Social'
             WHEN utm_medium = 'email' THEN channel = 'Email'  
        END)
FROM pageviews pv CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN url LIKE 'utm_medium' 
                   THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(pv.url, 'utm_medium=', 2
                                             ), '&', 1
                                  )
             )
     ) v(utm_medium)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to query `utm_medium` column just after it is created?

Most likely not.

Some engines may support this non standard SQL feature you want. You don't mention which database you are using, so it's not clear.

The general solution for this is to produce a bona fide column with the name you want using a *table expression* or a CTE.

For example:

```
select
  col1, 
  col2,
  CASE 
  WHEN utm_medium = 'paidsocial'
    THEN channel = 'Paid Social'
  WHEN utm_medium = 'email'
    THEN channel = 'Email'  
  END
from (
  select
    col1,
    col2,
    CASE WHEN url LIKE 'utm_medium' 
      THEN
        SPLIT_PART( -- slice UTM from URL
          SPLIT_PART(pageviews.url,'utm_medium=',2)
          ,'&',1
        )
      ELSE NULL 
    END AS utm_medium
  from my_table
) x
```

This example will run on virtually all databases. As you see a table expression `x` was used in the `FROM` clause, effectively defining a column called `utm_medium` in it. Then, the main query can simply use this column right away.